# How to declare an std::array of structs initialised inline with different values

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, stdarray

I am trying to a initialise an array of structs in a `std::array`. I know that the following is a way of initialising an `std::array` with integers.

```
std::array<int, 5> arr { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} };
```

**Scenario:**
But, say I have an array of structs like this

```
struct MyStruct {
    const char     *char_val_1;
    const char     *char_val_2;
    int             int_val_1;
    double          d_val_1;
} my_struct_obj[] = {
    { "a1b1"    , "a2b1"    , 1  ,   1.1 },
    { "a1b2"    , "a3b1"    , 2  ,   1.2 },
    { "a1b3"    , "a4b1"    , 3  ,   1.3 },
    { "a1b4"    , "a5b1"    , 4  ,   1.4 },
    { "a1b5"    , "a6b1"    , 5  ,   1.5 },
    { "a1b6"    , "a7b1"    , 6  ,   1.6 },
    { "a1b7"    , "a8b1"    , 7  ,   1.7 },
    { "a1b8"    , "a9b1"    , 8  ,   1.8 },
    { "a1b9"    , "a10b1"   , 9  ,   1.9 },
};
```

**Question:**
How can I create an `std::array` of `MyStruct`s each initialised with different set of values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like for integers, provide initializers for each value:

```
std::array<MyStruct, 9> my_struct_arr = {{
    { "a1b1"    , "a2b1"    , 1  ,   1.1 },
    { "a1b2"    , "a3b1"    , 2  ,   1.2 },
    { "a1b3"    , "a4b1"    , 3  ,   1.3 },
    { "a1b4"    , "a5b1"    , 4  ,   1.4 },
    { "a1b5"    , "a6b1"    , 5  ,   1.5 },
    { "a1b6"    , "a7b1"    , 6  ,   1.6 },
    { "a1b7"    , "a8b1"    , 7  ,   1.7 },
    { "a1b8"    , "a9b1"    , 8  ,   1.8 },
    { "a1b9"    , "a10b1"   , 9  ,   1.9 },
}};
```